# Triangle identification generator

Tags: python

If all three angles are 60,  output Equilateral
If the three angles add up to 180 and exactly two of the angles are the same,   output Isosceles
If the three angles add up to 180 and no two angles are the same,   output Scalene
If the 3 angles do not add up to 180 or any of the angles are 0 or negative,   output Not a Triangle

These are my instructions. My problem is that when I test for equilateral and all sides are 60, “isosceles” also gets generated in my print statement because two sides are 60. How can I fix this? And how can I make sure my numbers stay equal to 180 and generate properly?

Here’s my code:

```
a = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle a:"))
b = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle b:"))
c = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle c:"))

#triangle calculations
add= a+b+c
Equilateral= 60+60+60

if a==60:
a is 60
  if b==60:
    b is 60
       if c== 60:
             c is 60
print("Equilateral")


if a!=b and a!=c and b!=c:
  print("Scalene")

    

if add>180:
  print("Not a triangle.")

if add<180:
  print("Not a triangle.")
```

**note: I am fully aware this is not good, I just didn’t know how to continue or what to change. I just started coding, I’m a HS junior so please be easy on me lol

Comment: Can you show us your code? We can't readily tell what you might be doing wrong without seeing it. Check out [ask] for more guidelines on asking good questions. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: What is the point of things like `a is 60`?

Comment: Indentation is important in python.  This is not valid python code.

Comment: `if a==b==c`, then it is equilateral.  Otherwise, `elif a==b or a==c or b==c` then it is isoceles.  Otherwise, it is scalene.  You must use `elif`, so you don't check the equilaterals again.

Answer (score 1):

Your program gives several different answers because your conditions overlap (for example, if a == 60 AND b == 60 AND c == 60 is true, then a == b is true too). Note that it's actually mathematically correct, because an equilateral triangle is a particular isosceles triangle. But, for the purpose of this program, we want only one answer (the best one) for each triangle. So:

- either use elif (else if) as said in one comment, so no two situations can be simultaneously true
- or use mutually exclusive conditions (but this way, testing for a pure isosceles triangle will be cumbersome, since you have to test that it exists (add = 180) and it is isosceles but not equilateral (hint: 2 sides must be equal, but not the 3rd).

I'll now provide an answer with exclusive conditions:

```
a = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle a: "))
b = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle b: "))
c = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle c: "))


if a + b + c != 180:
    print("Not a triangle.")
    
    
if a + b + c == 180 and a != b and a != c and b != c:
    print("Scalene")
    
if a == 60 and b == 60 and c == 60:
    print("Equilateral")

# And now the "hard" (or rather unwieldy) one: you must test that the triangle
# is valid, and isosceles but NOT equilateral (2 sides equal but NOT the third)

if (a + b + c == 180) and ((a == b and a != c) or (a == c and a != b) or (b == c and b != a)):
    print("isosceles")
```

And the modified version with elif: note that it's shorter, since you don't have to repeat tests already performed:

```
a = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle a: "))
b = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle b: "))
c = int(input("Enter the degrees of angle c: "))



if a + b + c != 180:
    print("Not a triangle.")
    
elif a != b and a != c and b != c:
    print("Scalene")
    
elif a == 60 and b == 60 and c == 60:
    print("Equilateral")

else:
    print("isosceles")
```